# List with several absolute urls "urljoin'ed"

Tags: python, scrapy

I wish to download all the files from the first post, of several forum topics of a specific [forum page](https://www.slightlymagic.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=48). I have my own file pipeline set up to take the items `file_url`, `file_name` and `source`(topic name), in order to save them to the folder `./source/file_name`.

However, the file links are relative and I need to use the absolute path. I tried `response.urljoin` and it gives me a `string` of the absolute url but of the last file of the post only.

Running the spider gives me the error `ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h` 
This happens because the absolute url is a `string` and not a `list`

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import FilespipelineItem


class MTGSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mtgd'
    base_url = 'https://www.slightlymagic.net/forum'
    subforum_url = '/viewforum.php?f=48'
    start_urls = [base_url + subforum_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        for topic_url in response.css('.row dl dt a.topictitle::attr(href)').extract():
            yield response.follow(topic_url, callback=self.parse_topic)

    def parse_topic(self, response):
        item = FilespipelineItem()

        item['source'] = response.xpath('//h2/a/text()').get()
        item['file_name'] = response.css('.postbody')[0].css('.file .postlink::text').extract()

        # Problematic code
        for file_url in response.css('.postbody')[0].css('.file .postlink::attr(href)').extract():
            item['file_url'] = response.urljoin(file_url)

        yield item
```

If it helps here's the pipeline code:

```
import re
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy import Request


class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for file_url in item['file_url']:
            yield Request(file_url,
                          meta={
                              'name': item['file_name'],
                              'source': item['source']
                          })

    # Rename files to their original name and not the hash
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        file = request.meta['name']
        source = request.meta['source']
        # Get names from previous function meta

        source = re.sub(r'[?\\*|"<>:/]', '', source)
        # Clean source name for windows compatible folder name

        filename = u'{0}/{1}'.format(source, file)
        # Folder storage key: {0} corresponds to topic name; {1} corresponds to filename

        return filename
```

So my question is.

In a topic with more than 1 file to be downloaded, how can I save the several absolute urls into the `file_url` item? The `for` loop is not working as intended since it only saves the last file's url.

Do I need a `for` loop for this problem? If so, what should it be?

Comment: maybe you should `yield` inside `for`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```py
    for file_url in response.css('.postbody')[0].css('.file .postlink::attr(href)').extract():
        item['file_url'] = response.urljoin(file_url)
```

You are overwriting `item['file_url']` every time with a new URL, and as a result the value of the last one is the value that stays.

Use Python list comprehension instead of a `for` loop:

```py
    file_urls = response.css('.postbody')[0].css('.file .postlink::attr(href)').extract():
    item['file_urls'] = [response.urljoin(file_url) for file_url in file_urls]
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. It's a simple solution but since i'm still learning I was struggling a bit to find it.